# Is it better to have one table with a flag or two separate tables?

Tags: mysql, domain-driven-design

So I have a process in which there is a queue of posts to be review for quality assurance.
These posts are "removed" from the page consuming the queue by filtering out those that are marked completed.

At certain intervals this queue is hydrated with more posts, including prior completed posts for re-assessment (given there does not already exist a non-completed entry for that post)

I am wondering if I am better suited to have one table, using the "completed_at" as a flag on whether or not an item is requeued OR two separate tables, one with incomplete items and the other with completed items.

**Post_Queue**

| id | post_id | created_at | completed_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 112 | 2022-01-1 | 2022-01-2 |
| 2 | 112 | 2022-01-3 | null |

------ OR ---------

**Post_Queue**

| id | post_id | created_at | completed_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 112 | 2022-01-3 | null |

**Post_Queue_Completed**

| id | post_id | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 112 | 2022-01-1 |

Comment: One table is enough. But do proper indexing.

Comment: One problem with the one table approach is I would have to query for an existing record of post_id and completed_at = null to determine there are no duplicate requeues. Or is there another approach I can take?

Comment: Not sure that should happen in that case but look at: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html. Also should that not be prevented in your program logic.

Comment: `ON DUPLICATE KEY` inserts are very powerful, highly recommend. If you're looking to build a queue, also consider explicit queue systems like [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com).